# *.edited file is created during merge

Tags: svn, ubuntu, meld

I added external merge tool (meld) to subversion on Ubuntu. Everything works fine, however when I resolve my conflict and accept the changes I see file being created that I merged, with ".edited" appended to it. So if I merged file test.txt I would get my merge changes in test.txt and also file created test.txt.edited with merge conflicts.

Does anybody know who creates this file and its creation can be disabled.

Comment: If you can't figure out what tool is creating the `.edited` file (and the `meld` documentation is nearly useless...) then you can try something drastic like `strace -o /tmp/meld -f <whatever command you're running>` and then look through the trace file `/tmp/meld` to figure out which process wrote the `.edited` file. (It's easier than it sounds...)

Comment: Thanks sarnold. I did look in Meld's preferences, but could find anything related to "edited" file creation. I ran strace against svn and merge.sh script, which is a wrapper for the svn merge so I can use Meld as my merge tool but neither had any references to .edited append. If I run svn merge manually then file is not being created, so it leaves only Meld. I did post question on Meld mailing list about this so hopefully someone knows something.

Answer (score 1):

The file is being created by subversion. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13256469/496321).

My guess is it happens when you edit the final file but you end up choosing mine-conflict, theirs-conflict, mine-full or theirs-full.

You can also check [this thread](http://subversion.1072662.n5.nabble.com/When-does-update-merge-conflict-produce-edited-file-td175590.html).