# SVN (Subclipse) creating .edited file after merge conflict

Tags: svn, subclipse

My Google-fu is apparently weak on this subject, so I'm hoping one of you can help me out! I recently upgraded to Subclipse 1.8, which implements SVN 1.7, and I've noticed that after resolving a merge conflict that it always creates a .edited file. For example, if I resolve a merge conflict on a file named "foo.txt", I am left with "foo.txt" and "foo.txt.edited". What is this .edited file, and is there some way that I can configure SVN or Subclipse to stop generating it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file is created by Subversion.  See:  http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/subversion/branches/1.7.x/subversion/libsvn_wc/merge.c?view=markup

I assume it is a transient file though and does not remain on disk in once you tell SVN the conflicts are resolved.  I would encourage you to document a step by step reproduction recipe and report it to Subclipse community.

http://subclipse.tigris.org/ds/viewForumSummary.do?dsForumId=1047

I am assuming this is something where we just need to ask Eclipse to "refresh" after some scenario plays out.

Comment: I agree that the file appears as though it _should_ be transient; it just appears that it's not being automatically removed after the resolution of a merge conflict. I've gone ahead, as you suggested, and reported the issue to the Subclipse community [here](http://subclipse.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=1047&dsMessageId=3026409). Thanks!